# How to add onEachFeature bind using react-leaflet

Tags: geodjango, react-leaflet

I have a django rest api that gives the following get response:

[image: counties]

Using django view, I can render the geojson as follows:

```
var kcount = L.geoJson();
$.getJSON("{% url 'counties' %}", function (data) {
  myLayer = new L.geoJson(data, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          layer.bindPopup('<font size="4">' + feature.properties.county_nam)
        },
        style: countStyle
 }).addTo(kcount).addTo(map);
});
```

My challenge is displaying the same using react-leaflet. How do I implement onEachFeature loop... and how can I just query a specific county?

```
<Map className="map" style={{height:'100%',width:'100%'}}>
      <GeoJSON data={geo}/>
</Map>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to popup everything, use the regular expression like this,

```js
onEach = (feature, layer) => {
    let popupContent =
      "<pre>" +
      JSON.stringify(feature.properties, null, " ").replace(/[\{\}"]/g, "") +
      "</pre>";
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
  };

<MapContainer>

  <GeoJSON data={geojsonData} onEachFeature={this.onEach} />
</MapContainer>
```

Comment: can u please help me . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73423447/my-local-api-data-is-not-working-react-leaflet

Answer (score 0):

on the GeoJSON object add onEeachFeature method, and generate the popup as:

```
..
onEach(feature,layer){
        let PopupContent = `
            <Popup>
                <p>county name:${feature.properties.county_nam}</p>
            </Popup>
        `
        layer.bindPopup(PopupContent)
    }
..
    <Map>
    <GeoJSON data={geo} onEachFeature={this.onEach}/>
    </Map>
```